# How to persist Entity in separate thread with JPA on J2EE App server?

Tags: multithreading, jpa, concurrency, jakarta-ee

I have a chat application that needs to store messages to DB. But connection with DB is a little bit slow, therefore it delays response to chat client.

Is it possible to persist Message entity in separate thread? What I'm actually need in: reduce delay before send-recieve message on client.

I try to do it, but it doen't work.

Dao object:

```
@Stateless
public class MessagesDAO {
    @PersistenceContext(type= PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private PersistenceThread persistenceThread = new PersistenceThread();

    //another methods

    public void addMessage(Message message) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(persistenceThread);
        persistenceThread.setMessage(message);
        thread.start();
    }

    private class PersistenceThread implements Runnable {
        private Message message;

        public void setMessage(Message message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void run() {
            entityManager.persist(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Interface service that calls DAO to persist new message and then return it to clients:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/messages")
@Produces("application/xml")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public class MessagesServiceImpl {
    @EJB
    private MessagesDAO messagesDAO;

    @POST
    @Broadcast(resumeOnBroadcast = true)
    public Message postMessage(Message message) {
        messagesDAO.addMessage(message);
        return message;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/wait")
    @Suspend(outputComments = false)
    public Message waitForLastMessage() {
        return null;
    }
    //another methods

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the [@Asynchronous](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) annotation a try:

```
@Stateless
public class MessagesDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Asynchronous
    public void addMessage(Message message) {
      entityManager.persist(message);
    }
}
```

Just bear in mind that it requires EJB 3.1.